# Hudson Apache SVN Checkout Exception - 500 internal Server Error

Tags: apache, svn, tomcat, continuous-integration, hudson

I'm hitting an error while trying to checkout an SVN Repo via Hudson.

With TortoiseSVN i can checkout this Repository without any Problems.

In Hudson I use the "Hudson Subversion Plug-in -2.3.8-h-1".

At the beginning I used this SVN Syntax: `svn://url/repo`

Now we changed our Repositories to VisualSVNManager and i hava following Syntax: `http://url:81/svn/repo`

My Hudson is running on an Apache Tomcat.

Error is:

```
    Checking out http://url:81/svn/repo revision: 23.04.2013 11:25:59 depth:infinity ignoreExternals: false
ERROR: Failed to check out http://url:81/svn/repo
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: REPORT of '/svn/repo/!svn/vcc/default': 500 Internal Server Error (http://url:81)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getDatedRevision(DAVRepository.java:207)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:178)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:151)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:45)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:706)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:14)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:9)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:777)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$UpdateTaskImpl.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:111)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:152)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:160)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:114)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:152)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:812)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:795)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:776)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:791)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:773)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:768)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:711)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1515)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:521)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:428)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1390)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:40)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:81)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What's logged to VisualSVN Server log? Check http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember wrong SVN version was that Problem had to change from 1.4 to 1.6.